# Unable to find System.Net.Http in web site project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with a web site project within Visual Studio 2015. I usually work with web applications so this type of project is new to me.

This application consist of ASP.NET pages (aspx and .cs code behind files). I wanted to add some code to one of the code behind files that would make use of the HttpClient library, however I cannot seem to add a reference to System.Net.Http. It is not present in the references. I do see that the project is targeting .NET 4.0. Could that be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use NuGet to install this assembly. Just run it in the Package Manager Console(View -> Other Windows ->  Package Manager Console):

```
Install-Package System.Net.Http
```

**UPDATE**

If you use .NET 4.0 then you can't install the latest version of System.Net.Http because it doesn't compatible with that framework. You have to use:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http -Version 2.0.20710
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do web applications have certain packages installed by default as compared to web sites? This is the first time I have run into where system.net was not already installed.

Comment: @webworm Hello. Glad to have been of help. .NET Framework 4.0 was released in 2008. The first version of System.Net.Http was published in 2012. So, .NET 4.0 not contains this package(no System.Net.Http.dll in the folder where installed .NET 4.0) . As a result you can not see System.Net.Http in the Reference  window

Comment: Thanks for the update! By the way I always thought that you and the other Decepticons were misunderstood and got the short end of the stick.The Autobots were just jealous because they couldn't fly.